# More than enough "Always succeed"? [ RAKU ]

Tags: grammar, raku, assertion

In the documentation of Grammars under Section :

> "Always succeed" assertion

I reproduced the example presented there, with added code to show the table produced, in each stage of the parsing mechanism :

```
use v6.d;

grammar Digifier {
    rule TOP { [ <.succ> <digit>+ ]+ }
    token succ   { <?> }
    token digit { <[0..9]> }
}

class Letters {
    has @!numbers;

    method digit ($/) { @!numbers.tail ~= <a b c d e f g h i j>[$/]; say '---> ' ~ @!numbers }
    method succ  ($/) { @!numbers.push: '!'; say @!numbers }
    method TOP   ($/) { make @!numbers[^(*-1)] }
}

say 'FINAL ====> ' ~ Digifier.parse('123 456 789', actions => Letters.new).made;
```

The result is the following:

```
[!]
---> !b
---> !bc
---> !bcd
[!bcd !]
---> !bcd !e
---> !bcd !ef
---> !bcd !efg
[!bcd !efg !]
---> !bcd !efg !h
---> !bcd !efg !hi
---> !bcd !efg !hij
[!bcd !efg !hij !]

FINAL ====> !bcd !efg !hij
```

I expected only 3 pushes in table @!numbers but I got 4.
I am puzzled about the need for an exclusion of the last value of table @!numbers in method "TOP".

Yes I know that the code produces the correct result but why?

Where does the last "Always Succeed" assertion come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quantified group, eg `[ A B ]+`, is effectively a loop, repeatedly attempting to match `A`, and iff that matches, attempting to match `B`.

Unless it's an infinite loop -- in which case your program will hang -- it will eventually match N times and then move on. If `A` *always* matches, but your program *doesn't* hang, then that must mean `B` eventually failed. If so, `A` is guaranteed to have matched one more time than `B`.

In your code, `A` is `<.succ>` which reduces to `<?>`, which always matches. There are 4 attempts and thus `A` matches **4** times. In contrast `B`, which is `<digit>+`, fails on the fourth attempt so only matches **3** times.